# Raise an event from a custom class

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a Windows Service project designed to monitor an email account and make entries into a SQL Server database when certain emails arrive. This is a rewrite of a similar winforms program that works just fine, except that it requires that the computer be logged into an account and the program started manually, which I can avoid by using it as a service.

In the service I maintain a list of logged messages - basically just a string and a timestamp indicating that something has happened. (That list is shared out over a WCF service but I think that's immaterial, at least at the moment.) In my custom class I declare a public event, and elsewhere I raise that event. For some reason, though, the `RaiseEvent` isn't being run in the service. For example:

```
Public Class TheService
    Private WithEvents _pc As ProcessorClass

    Public Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        _pc = New ProcessorClass
    End Sub
    ...
    Private Sub _pc_HandleEvent(LogMessage As String) Handles _pc.CustomEvent
        'do something with the LogMessage
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ProcessorClass
    Public Event CustomEvent(ByVal LogMessage As String)
    ...
    Public Sub Process()
        'Do stuff
        RaiseEvent CustomEvent("Event raised")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem in this case is that `_pc_HandleEvent` isn't ever being called. If I duplicate this setup in a regular winform program, everything works like it should. What am I doing wrong? How do I get a service to handle events raised from other classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little more testing and I solved it. I was trying to raise the event in my constructor, but since it hadn't completed constructing (?) the class the handler wasn't attached at that point. So now instead I create a new object first, which gives the handler something to grab onto, then call a public method in that class that does what I had been doing in the class constructor. Now that the handler is registered, it catches the events as they're raised.